# Check if appnext was successfully integrated in phonegap, Android

Tags: android, debugging, cordova, testing

I want to publish ads from AppNext to my app. I built my app with Cordova/Phonegap. I don't use Eclipse or Android Studio, or any other IDE. I use only Notepad++ and Windows Explorer :D. I followed the instructions for integrating AppNext in phonegap (I put the jar into the Libs, modified the manifest..). Now, how can I test if works? I compiled and I don't see any ads..

** I have internet connection..

Comment: their phonegap SDK is broken. I'm in contact with them for the same...If you try the callback function of the initialization, you will get "invalid action"...their SDK is broken and they are taking so much to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have support for Phonegap.